# Grails: How to insert with many-to-many with extra column?

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

Take the example of `author`, `book` and with a join table `author_books` with an extra `royalty` column:

```
CREATE TABLE 'author_books' (
    'author_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    'book_id' bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    'royalty' int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('author_id', 'book_id') ,
    INDEX 'FK24C812F6183CFE1B' ('book_id'),
    INDEX 'FK24C812F6DAE0A69B' ('author_id')
```

)

If I don't have the db-reverse-engineer plugin generate the AuthorBooks class, the generated code would be:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    String title
    static hasMany = [authors: Author]
    static belongsTo = [Author]
}
```

The following code:

```
def author1 = new Author(name: 'author1').addToBooks(new Book(title: 
                         'book1')).save(flush: true)
```

would insert one row into `author` table and one row in `book` table, but would fail to insert into `author_books` because `royalty` cannot be null.

However if have the db-reverse-engineer plugin generate the AuthorBooks class, the generated code would be:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [authorBookses: AuthorBooks]
}

class Book {
    String title
    static hasMany = [authorBookses: AuthorBooks]
}

class AuthorBooks implements Serializable {
    Long authorId
    Long bookId
    Integer royalty
    Author author
    Book book

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append authorId
        builder.append bookId
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (other == null) return false
        def builder = new EqualsBuilder()
        builder.append authorId, other.authorId
        builder.append bookId, other.bookId
        builder.isEquals()
    }

    static belongsTo = [author: Author, book: Book]

    static mapping = {
        author insertable: false       // these insertable and updateable codes were manually added
        author updateable: false       // otherwise it would not run
        book insertable: false
        book updateable: false
        id composite: ["authorId", "bookId"]
        version false
   }
}
```

In this case, I cannot call `author.addToAuthorBooks(new AuthorBooks( ))` because  `author_books` cannot have `author_id` or `book_id` to be `null`. In the end I need to do the following to get it work:

```
def author1 = new Author(name: 'author1').save(flush: true)
def book1 = new Book(title: 'book1').save(flush: true)
def authorbook1 = new AuthorBooks(authorId: author1.id, bookId: book1.id, 
                      royalty: 50, author: author1, book: book1).save(flush: true)
```

which is acceptable to me. But then what is the benefits of having hasMany association in the Author and Book class? Any better way to do this? Ideally, something like following would be cool

```
def author1 = new Author(name: 'author1').addToBooks(book: new Book(title: 'book1'), 
                         royalty: 50).save(flush: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes that I would like to recommend,specifically in your AuthorBooks domain:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [authorBookses: AuthorBooks]
}

class Book {
    String title
    static hasMany = [authorBookses: AuthorBooks]
}

class AuthorBooks implements Serializable {
    Integer royalty
    Author author
    Book book

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append author.id
        builder.append book.id
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (other == null) return false
        def builder = new EqualsBuilder()
        builder.append author.id, other.author.id
        builder.append book.id, other.book.id
        builder.isEquals()
    }

    static belongsTo = [author: Author, book: Book]

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ["author", "book"]
        version false
   }
}
```

Having additional ids for book and author is redundant. I'm not 100% sure about what I'm going to suggest, but it would be worth of trying the following:

```
def author1 = new Author(name: 'author1', authorBookses: new HashSet())
def book1 = new Book(title: 'book1', authorBookses: new HashSet())
def authorbook1 = new AuthorBooks(royalty: 50, author: author1, book: book1)

author1.authorBookses(authorbook1)
book1.authorBookses(authorbook1)

authorbook1.save(flush: true)
```

Comment: That seems the right approach. Here is the code with some minor modifications:

Comment: That seems the right approach. (the code need some syntax changes: `new AuthorBooks( )` does not have `authorId` and `bookId` arguments; and `author1` and `book1` both calls `addToAuthorBooks(authorbook1)` instead of `authorBookses(authorbook1)`). But the call `authorbook1.save(flush: true)` result in `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: null`. Seems the `save()` call caused the NPE.

Comment: Yes, I've overlooked that. Updated the answer.